# Please use compiler that supports __attribute__((constructor))

Tags: gcc, configure, ucx

I just compiled my own version of gcc/9.2.0 using gcc/4.8.2. After successful compilation and installation of gcc/9.2.0 I try compiling ucx-1.5.1. When I try to run the ucx configure script I get the following message "checking **attribute**((constructor))... configure: error: Cannot continue. Please use compiler that supports **attribute**((constructor))". 
When I run the script using the old  gcc/4.8.2 I get no error at all.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that the gcc/9.2.0 does not support "__attribute__((constructor))" ?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what went wrong?
>   No.

You can have a look at the respective `config.log` file, it usually contains additional information.  In general, not every compilation error during `configue` indicates a problem, it's usually just feature test that just revealed a specific feature is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Ucx uses [next code](https://github.com/openucx/ucx/blob/72ae40c607067b6dfadf0d208f6811171bbf36b6/config/m4/ucs.m4#L140-L150) to determine support of attribute `__attribute__((constructor))`. You can test it by yourself:

```sh
gcc -x c - <<EOF 
static int rc = 1;
static void constructor_test() __attribute__((constructor));
static void constructor_test() { rc = 0; }
int main() { return rc; }
EOF
```

And post here if you have some errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because I installed a software named "binutils-devel" on CentOS 8.4.

When "binutils-devel" was removed, the compile of ucx was successful.